# logger instance with two xml file

Tags: java, xml, log4j, classpath

I have need of two instances of logger that bind with different xml files at one time execution but in my case when I bind the xml path with first invoked logger, it does not release the earlier added path. so I am not able to bind the another xml path.

FYI: I am using `System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile","xml_path")` to bind the xml path as i placed xml file at external directory.

it works fine, logger dump file in well manner but when i try to bind the another xml path by above mentioned way, it does't accept. logger instance shows path of first xml file on inspecting config file property.

so what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext ctx =
                (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
            ctx.reconfigure();
```

use this to reconfgure the xml path at run time. I solved my problem with this.